# java sealed interfaces with records inheritance

Tags: java

I'm trying to crear an domain error hierarchy using sleaded interfaces and records:

Here my code:

```java
public sealed interface DomainError permits ReferenceError {

}
```

```java
public sealed interface ReferenceError extends DomainError permits ReferenceError.ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError, ReferenceError.ReferenceTransactionIdNonNullError {

    record ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError(String message) implements ReferenceError {
    }

    record ReferenceTransactionIdNonNullError(String message) implements ReferenceError {
    }

}
```

I'm trying to write this code snippet:

```java
public static Validation<ReferenceError, ReferenceUniqueIdentifier> uniqueIdentifierNonNull(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(referenceUniqueIdentifier)
        .map(Validation::<ReferenceError.ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError, ReferenceUniqueIdentifier>valid)
        .orElse(Validation.invalid(new ReferenceError.ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError("Reference unique Identifier can't be null")));
    }
```

I'm getting:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Validation<ReferenceError.ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError,ReferenceUniqueIdentifier> to Validation<ReferenceError,ReferenceUniqueIdentifier>

Why I'm not able to return a `Validation<ReferenceError.ReferenceUniqueIdenfifierNonNullError, reference>` as `Validation<RerenceError>`?
Why I'm not able to return a sub-class on Validation

Comment: Don't you need `ReferenceError.` before the names of the records in the `permit` clause? Do you have a `import static` or something?

Comment: Wring ``ReferenceError.`on permits clause works. Why?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70479464/5133585 which is similar. `ReferenceUniqueIdentifierNonNullError` is not in scope in the `permit` clause.

Comment: I chaned post inheritance issue on post... Could you take a look? I'm getting that can't return a subclass sealed class?

Comment: That's just https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5133585. You can return `Validation<? extends ReferenceError, ...>`.

Comment: Not cool to edit the question to something completely different.  If you already had any answers then I would roll it back, but it's still poor form even without.